# How to retrieve SMS message after a given date with python in Twilio API

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to retrieve SMS messages from a twilio message list before a given date. It works when i ask it for a given date with an equal sign (it returns all SMS on Feb 2, 2019:

```
 timestamp = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 15, 0, 0,0)
 client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

 messages = client.messages.list(
                           date_sent=timestamp
                       )
```

But if I try to use:

```
 date_sent<=timestamp
```

or

```
 date_sent>=timestamp
```

I get an error.

```
global name 'date_sent' is not defined
```

The docs seems to suggest you can use >= or <= operators but it doesn't work in practice this way. Any ideas how to get this to spit the right data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here! Great question, this isn't well documented. I'll work with the team to fix that.

The python library has a different parameter for filter before a date, so what you'll need is `date_sent_before` instead of `date_sent`:

```
import os
import datetime

from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']

timestamp = datetime(2019, 2, 15, 0, 0,0)
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# retrieve all messages before a given date
messages = client.messages.list(date_sent_before=timestamp)

print(len(messages1))
print(len(messages2))
```

Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: this helped! Thank you! and date_sent_after works for the converse!

Comment: Thank you for this. Has the official documentation been updated yet? I have not seen it...